# Jquery validate com type button

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Olá, tenho um formulário que usa direto javascript para enviar os dados, e o type dele é button.

`<button type="button" id="login_submit_patient" class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air uppercase">`

Porém não consigo usar o jquery validate sem for type submit.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login-form-patient").validate({
        rules: {
           ........
        }
  });
```

Alguém sabe como fazer? obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) que retorna `true` ou `false` dependendo se o seu formulário é válido ou não.

```js
$("#login_submit_patient").on("click",function(){
  if(!$("form").valid())
    console.log("Formulário inválido");
});

$("form").validate({
    messages: {
        name: "Nome obrigatório",
        email: {
            required: "E-mail obrigatório"
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="login_submit_patient">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: vlw amigo, deu certo.